# "Ambiguous use of 'firesOnRecordCreation'" when making a CKQuerySubscription

Tags: ios, cloudkit

Xcode is throwing a very ambiguous error:

> Ambiguous use of 'firesOnRecordCreation'

when making a CKQuerySubscription. Actually it does that on every option added to that call. Is that a compiler bug? Solution?

```swift
let predicate = NSPredicate(value: true)
let subscriptionID = "notes-changed"
let noteSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(recordType: "Notes",
                                                   predicate: predicate,
                                                   subscriptionID: subscriptionID,
                                                   options: [.firesOnRecordCreation,
                                                             .firesOnRecordDeletion,
                                                             .firesOnRecordUpdate])
```

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Which version of Xcode and Swift are you using? If you are on **Swift 5**, you need to use the full `CKQuerySubscription.Options` name like this:

```
let noteSubscription = CKQuerySubscription(
  recordType: "Notes", 
  predicate: NSPredicate(value: true), 
  subscriptionID: "notes-changed", 
  options: [
    CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordCreation, 
    CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordUpdate, 
    CKQuerySubscription.Options.firesOnRecordDeletion
  ]
)
```

I hope that helps.

Comment: Thanks! I do hope apple stops renaming items in Swift frameworks soon.